# Emberjs Blocking Bootstrap Events

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-cli

Installed 1.13.8 ember (ember cli)

installed bootstrap with bower install --save bootstrap

Went to the application.hbs and pasted the [nav-pills](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills) example 
and did an ember server.

And when I click on the nav buttons they don't toggle color, the hover DO work. I tried to paste a glyph to see if that would work and it DID, so I think bootstrap is linked correctly.

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember</h2>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
{{outlet}}
```

should this not work? or does ember block the click events that bootstrap needs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you definitely importing Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript files correctly in your Brocfile?

```
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

This would be the first think I'd say to check as it sounds like you're missing the JavaScript file.

Comment: I don't have Brocfile, but have ember-cli-build.js which does not point to bootstrap. Apparently Brocfiles are no longer used in ember? http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/embercli-not-creating-brocfile-js/8388/9  how would I import it in ember-cli-build.js?

Comment: Ah, fair point! Not something I was aware of as I'm still working with an older version of Ember and Ember-cli. According to the docs it's fairly straight-forward. https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#how

Just replace the `app.imports()` in the ember-cli-build.js example with the location of your Bootstrap .js and .css files and let me know if that solves the problem.

Comment: Nope tried it, and it still doesn't work right. I also tried wrapping it in a container, but didn't work.

Comment: looking around, it looks like raw bootstrap doesn't play well in Ember 
https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap
Turre that you need to "emberiz" the bootstrap syntax.